# Mysql - sql How to get min time and max time record from second table which is include first table id

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT c.class_id,c.class_name,c.capacity,c.start_date,c.end_date

FROM `learningcenter_class` as cLEFT JOIN 
( SELECT min(start_time) as min_time, max(end_time) as max_time
 FROM learningcenter_sessions 
 GROUP BY class_id 
)  s ON  s.class_id =c.class_id
WHERE c.start_date between now() and now() + INTERVAL 1 MONTH ORDER BY 
created_date ASC
```

I have 2 table 1 is class other one is session. I want to get classes with min time and max time for this class. I m using mysql database. it s getting error

## 1054 - Unknown column 'c.class_id' in 'field list'

Comment: first of all fix typo `cLEFT` missing space `c LEFT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not select `class_id` in the inner SQL. Add this column to the select list

```
SELECT class_id , min(start_time) as min_time, max(end_time) as max_time
 FROM learningcenter_sessions 
 GROUP BY class_id
```